# How to align the number of values in the list?

Tags: r, list, alignment, xts

I have a list with three xts that contains one column.

```
:'xts' : 250 obs. of 1 variable:
:'xts' : 245 obs. of 1 variable:
:'xts' : 250 obs. of 1 variable:
```

XTS second number of values is smallest.

How to balance the number of variables in this list?
(It is worth remembering that the XTS has a variable as the time.)

Below is an example of how I would do:

```
index    time       xts1 xts2 xts3
    1    2016-10-27  10  34  7
    2    2016-10-26  41      16
    3    2016-10-25  19  60  25
    4    2016-10-24  50      92
    5    2016-10-23  34  75  6
```

If some values not, just delete the rows with a missing value.
That is, remove the 2 and 4 row into the list.

Answer (score 3):

It's worth it to begin using `NA` for missing values and not blank spaces. For data structure purposes it matters to make this adjustment. Many R objects must be of one type. Inserting blanks causes matrices and vectors to be coerced to type `"character"`. This is not the desired behavior if functions requiring `numeric` elements will be used.

You can subset an `xts` object just as you would a matrix:

```
#Example
mat
               Open     High      Low    Close
2007-01-02 50.03978 50.11778 49.95041 50.11778
2007-01-03 50.23050       NA 50.23050 50.39767
2007-01-04 50.42096 50.42096 50.26414 50.33236
2007-01-05 50.37347       NA 50.22103 50.33459
2007-01-06 50.24433 50.24433 50.11121 50.18112
2007-01-07 50.13211 50.21561 49.99185 49.99185
2007-01-08 50.03555       NA 49.96971 49.98806
2007-01-09 49.99489 49.99489 49.80454 49.91333
```

We can subset as we normally would:

```
mat2 <- mat[!is.na( mat[,2] ),]
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your data is in a dataframe, you could do:

```
df[rowSums(df[,3:5] == '') == 0,]
```

the result:

```
  index       time xts1 xts2 xts3
1     1 2016-10-27   10   34    7
3     3 2016-10-25   19   60   25
5     5 2016-10-23   34   75    6
```

If the missing values are represented by `NA`s, then you should change it to:

```
df[rowSums(is.na(df[,3:5])) == 0,]
```

The advantage of using `rowSums` is that you can check for missing values in multiple columns.

---

As @aichao noted, when you have separate `xts` objects, you can use `merge` with `all = FALSE` to combine them into one. However, I would use a combination of `Reduce` and `merge` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8097519/2204410)):

```
xts.c <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = FALSE), list(xts1,xts2,xts3))
names(xts.c) <- c('xts1','xts2','xts3')
```

the result:

```
> xts.c
           xts1 xts2 xts3
2016-10-23   34   75    6
2016-10-25   19   60   25
2016-10-27   10   34    7
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your xts objects are already in a list, the easiest thing to do is use `do.call` to call `merge` with your list. `do.call` allows you to pass a list of objects to `merge` instead of having to type all their names by hand.

```
library(xts)
# example data
dates <- seq(as.Date("2016-10-23"), as.Date("2016-10-27"), by = "day")
xtslist <- list(
  xts1 = xts(c(34, 50, 19, 41, 10), dates),
  xts2 = xts(c(75, 60, 34), dates[c(1, 3, 5)]),
  xts3 = xts(c(6, 92, 25, 16, 7), dates))
# merge all list elements into a single xts object
# Note: do.call(merge, xtslist) is equivalent to
#       merge(xtslist[[1]], xtslist[[2]], xtslist[[3]])
(myxts <- do.call(merge, xtslist))
#            xts1 xts2 xts3
# 2016-10-23   34   75    6
# 2016-10-24   50   NA   92
# 2016-10-25   19   60   25
# 2016-10-26   41   NA   16
# 2016-10-27   10   34    7
```

If you want to omit the rows with `NA`, you can either call `na.omit(myxts)`, or you can use the `all = FALSE` argument to `merge.xts`. Here's how you would specify `all = FALSE` in your `do.call` command.

```
(myxts2 <- do.call(merge, c(xtslist, all = FALSE)))
#            xts1 xts2 xts3
# 2016-10-23   34   75    6
# 2016-10-25   19   60   25
# 2016-10-27   10   34    7
```